# check img title to trigger a jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, reload

I am trying to reload a jqgrid depending on the title of a image. If the title is liveON it should go inside but it isn't. What is the problem? Do I need to get the title parametre with jquery? Thanks in advance.

```
 function reloadJson(){
   alert("Go!");
  if (document.getElementById("auto_reload").title == "liveON")
  {      
        $('#list').trigger("reloadGrid");
    }    
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use all jQuery? For example, "$('#auto_reload').attr('title')".  The only other small suggestion I would make is make sure the id is unique and/or check for typos in the title and/or id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use jQuery:

```
if ($("#auto_reload").attr("title") == "liveON")
{      
    $('#list').trigger("reloadGrid");
}
```